# Remove parent object of a JSON if it has certain property

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I'm getting a JSON structure from an API, that I want to change in my front end. The frontend adds a property to the JSON structure, "isHidden". When I send the modified JSON back, I don't want the object that has "isHidden" to be sent back to the API, but I will still save that internally in my own mongodb.

However, doing this was aperently a bit harder then I thought. I made this function wich works but I think is very ugly:

```
function removeHiddenObject(data,parent){
    for(var property in data){
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(property)){
            if(property == "isHidden" && data[property] === true){
                parent.splice(parent.indexOf(data), 1);
            }
            else {
                if(typeof data[property] === "object") {
                    removeHiddenObject(data[property], data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

It's a recursive method, but I find it way to complex and weird. Is there a way of simplifying my task?

Here is a jsfiddle for you if you'd like to help out: https://jsfiddle.net/vn4vbne8/

Comment: Would it be easier to treat the JSON as a string and replace the `isHidden` and then convert the string back to JSON !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code to remove it from json string :

```
myJson=s.replace(/,*\s*"[^"]"\s*\:\s*{(.*?)"isHidden"\:([^}]*)}/gm,"");
```

Be careful in Regex every character is important so use exactly above code.
It removes every property that have an object that one of its properties is isHidden.

Comment: I actually want to remove the whole object "isHidden" is attached to. So if it has the property isHidden, all of the sibling properties should also be removed. This does not do that? Or does it?

Comment: I edited the answer so now it works like you just said.

Comment: Ok, this apparently does not work with my company policies, avoid regular expressions for as much as possible. I'll mark this answer correct since it works.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript actually supports non-enumerable public properties. I'm assuming that when you send data back to the server you first stringify it with `JSON.stringify` which will only stringify public *enumerable* properties of the object.

You can define a non-enumerable property like this (more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)):

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'isHidden', {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true
});
```

Where `obj` is the javascript object you want to add the property to and `isHidden` is the name of the property you are adding. When done this way, the new property is accessible as `obj.isHidden` but nevertheless will not show up in `JSON.stringify` output nor in `for` loops.

Comment: I want the whole property, that the `isHidden` property is attached to, to be removed. This doesn't solve that, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Takes a bit of time to wrap your head around it, but it helps with some heavy lifting around general data processing.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = {"user":{"name":"Bob"},"buildingBlockTree":[{"uid":"a875ed6cf4052448f9e0cc9ff092a76d4","_id":"56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6ae","columns":[{"uid":"a0061fdd2259146bb84e5362eeb775186","_id":"56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6b1","buildingBlocks":[{"user":{"name":"lajdi"},"buildingBlockTree":[{"uid":"a875ed6cf4052448f9e0cc9ff092a76d4","_id":"56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6ae","columns":[{"uid":"a0061fdd2259146bb84e5362eeb775186","_id":"56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6b1","buildingBlocks":[]},{"uid":"abbcf3328854840deb96bb6b101df2b39","_id":"56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6af","buildingBlocks":[{"uid":"a931cf745d4b847ba9cdc7f4b830413be","_id":"56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6b0","source":{"limit":1,"itemsListId":1,"offset":0}}]}],"template":{"name":"Xs12Sm12Md6Lg12DotXs12Sm12Md6Lg12"}}],"_id":"56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6ad","source":{"limit":1,"itemsListId":1,"offset":0},"template":{"numberOfColumns":1},"uid":"a5f6a2fd1c80f49c0b97e0c7994400588"}]},{"uid":"abbcf3328854840deb96bb6b101df2b39","_id":"56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6af","buildingBlocks":[{"_id":"56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6b0","source":{"limit":1,"itemsListId":1,"offset":0},"isHidden":true}]}]}],"_id":"56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6ad","source":{"limit":1,"itemsListId":1,"offset":0},"uid":"a5f6a2fd1c80f49c0b97e0c7994400588","metadata":{"title":"sss"},"title":"sss","url":"sss"};

const removeHiddenObjects = (input) => objectScan(['**[*].isHidden'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ value, gparent, gproperty }) => {
    if (value === true) {
      gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(input);

console.log(removeHiddenObjects(data)); // counts removals
// => 1
console.log(data);
/* => {
  user: { name: 'Bob' },
  buildingBlockTree: [ {
    uid: 'a875ed6cf4052448f9e0cc9ff092a76d4',
    _id: '56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6ae',
    columns: [ {
      uid: 'a0061fdd2259146bb84e5362eeb775186',
      _id: '56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6b1',
      buildingBlocks: [ {
        user: { name: 'lajdi' },
        buildingBlockTree: [ {
          uid: 'a875ed6cf4052448f9e0cc9ff092a76d4', _id: '56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6ae', columns: [
            { uid: 'a0061fdd2259146bb84e5362eeb775186', _id: '56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6b1', buildingBlocks: [] },
            { uid: 'abbcf3328854840deb96bb6b101df2b39', _id: '56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6af', buildingBlocks: [
              { uid: 'a931cf745d4b847ba9cdc7f4b830413be', _id: '56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6b0', source: {
                limit: 1,
                itemsListId: 1,
                offset: 0
              } }
            ] }
          ],
          template: { name: 'Xs12Sm12Md6Lg12DotXs12Sm12Md6Lg12' }
        } ],
        _id: '56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6ad',
        source: { limit: 1, itemsListId: 1, offset: 0 },
        template: { numberOfColumns: 1 },
        uid: 'a5f6a2fd1c80f49c0b97e0c7994400588'
      } ]
    }, { uid: 'abbcf3328854840deb96bb6b101df2b39', _id: '56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6af', buildingBlocks: [] } ]
  } ],
  _id: '56a7353f682e1cc615f4a6ad',
  source: { limit: 1, itemsListId: 1, offset: 0 },
  uid: 'a5f6a2fd1c80f49c0b97e0c7994400588',
  metadata: { title: 'sss' },
  title: 'sss',
  url: 'sss'
}
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@16.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)